# How to capture time to the first event?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame such like:

```
set.seed(123)
df<-data.frame(id=rep(LETTERS[1:3],each=4),
               days=as.integer(rnorm(12,100,10)),
               event=rbinom(12,1,0.3))
df<-df[with(df,order(id,days)),]
df$event[sample(3,1:12,T)]<-NA
df[2,3]<-0
df
   id days event
1   A   94     0
2   A   97     0
4   A  100    NA
3   A  115     0
8   B   87     1
5   B  101     0
7   B  104     1
6   B  117     0
9   C   93     0
10  C   95     1
12  C  103     0
11  C  112     0
```

How could I capture the `days` to first `event=1` by ignoring NAs and if there's no event then return the max days such that:

```
df2
   id days event
3   A  115     0
8   B   87     1
10  C   95     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With problems like this, it is usually best to split them into smaller chunks. First we need a function to select the correct event for a given id. So something like:

```
get_index = function(event) {
  test = (event==1)
  if(sum(test, na.rm=TRUE)) 
    return(which.max(event))
  else
    return(max(which(!test)))
}
```

and a quick sanity check:

```
R> event = c(0, 0, NA, 0)
R> get_index(event)
[1] 4
R> event = c(0, 1, 0, 0)
R> get_index(event)
[1] 2
```

Next we split the data up by id and apply the function, so

```
R> library(plyr)
R> ddply(df, .(id), summarize, 
                    days = days[get_index(event)], 
                    event=event[get_index(event)])
  id days event
1  A  115     0
2  B   87     1
3  C   95     1
```

We could make this much more efficient (we are calling `get_index` twice), but this should get you started.

Answer (score 4):

This is squeezed into one line and uses `data.table`:

```
require(data.table) ## >= 1.9.2
setDT(df)[, min(days[event==1], max(days), na.rm=TRUE), by=id]
```

It works as requested, but I still suggest you split it into two (event encountered, and no event encountered) and merge the tables. This relies on `min()` returning `Inf` when given a vector of length 0. In that case `max(days)` kicks in.

`setDT` converts the `data.frame` to `data.table` by reference.